# CGPS stuck on no fix (0 secs) on Debian VM, missing step in my sequence?

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, gpsd

I am using a USB GPS device on a Debian VM (running on a windows host) that is initiated by a program to run gpspipe (from gpsd) and collect data, the host device will frequently reboot (by design) and I have set the VM to reboot along with this, however on the reboot the GPS device does not appear to function correctly. When I run cgps it outputs "No fix (0s) and will simply stay static like that.

The `/etc/default/gpsd` file is set to:

```
START_DAEMON = "true"
DEVICES=""
GPSD_OPTIONS=""
USBAUTO="true"
```

on reboot a .sh file is called by crontab that has this line initiating the gps

```
gpspipe -w | grep TPV > "file_location
```

When I first rebooted after this I checked using cgps and while it did not initially find a fix it did start collecting satellites and incrementing the time. However at this point I opened powershell outside of the VM to check another location program (that should also call the gps) I think this had an effect as when i checked with cgps it had stopped collecting data and then the VM wouldn't recognised the USB device on reboot, I rebooted the whole PC and the VM recognised the device again but was back to the same issue with just getting static no data through.

I'm not sure if in my .sh file that calls gpspipe I should have a line to kill gpsd and remove the socket before re-initialising? I thought that was somewhat covered by the usbauto line in the config file as I've not had this issue before but am not overly familiar with the configuration of these devices and feel I may be missing something.